# Is it possible to display the full URL in the tooltip of a Chrome tab (on hover)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Is it possible to display the full URL of a webpage when hovering over a tab in Chrome, instead of just the domain? And is it possible to do so programatically, not by editing a local configuration in Chrome.

Below are two images comparing tab tooltips in Chrome and IE. I am wondering if it possible somehow to make the tooltip in Chrome display the entire url like IE does instead of just the domain.

Current Chrome tab tooltip:

[image]

IE Tab Tooltip:

[image]

Comment: I think you could build a chrome extension for this. Other than that I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Would you like to focus your users about your site's full URL?

Comment: @Bluefire828 yes, I have concluded that its not possible using traditional web-dev tools. Perhaps you could do it using an extension but I've resorted to putting the relevant info I wanted into the title tag of my page.

Answer (score 0):

First: You didn't clarify What are you trying to target and How your app/code written?.

If you want your users focus on your page full title or/and full page URL, Try the below as workaround.

**Method #1: using custom tooltip** (with `mouseout` and `mouseover` events to show & hide title)

```
var ttl = document.title,
  loc = document.location,
  fullTitle = ttl + "\n" + loc,
  isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
var tooltip = document.createElement("div");
tooltip.style.width = "400px"
tooltip.style.borderRadius = "10px"
tooltip.style.position = "fixed"
tooltip.style.left = "40%"
tooltip.style.top = "3%"
tooltip.style.padding = "15px"
tooltip.style.marginTop = "8px"
tooltip.style.visibility = "hidden"
tooltip.style.backgroundColor = "white"
tooltip.style.zIndex = "9999"
tooltip.style.border = "solid 1px #ccc"
tooltip.innerHTML = "<b>" + document.title + "</b><br/><br/>" + document.location;
document.body.appendChild(tooltip);
if (isChrome) {
  document.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    tooltip.style.visibility = "visible"
  });
  document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    tooltip.style.visibility = "hidden";
  });
}
```

**Method #2: Something like rotational title:**

```
var ttl = document.title, 
    loc = document.location, 
fullTitle = ttl + " - " + loc,
document.title = fullTitle;


if(isChrome)rotaryTitle(50);

function rotaryTitle(speed, tempPause) {
  speed = speed || 100;
  setTimeout(function() {
    var t = document.title;
    if (t.length > 1) {
      document.title = t.substr(1);
      rotaryTitle(speed);
    } else {
      document.title = fullTitle;
      rotaryTitle(speed, 2000);
    }
  }, tempPause || speed)
}
```